# Best setup for virtual machines

Tags: networking, kvm-virtualization

Today I have a Ubuntu Server with one lan connection (eht0) and two internet connections with one provider dedicated ip each (eth1 and eth2). I would like to change this setup to a new Ubuntu Server with two virtual machines (KVM). Each virtual machine will work with one of the internet connections and a bridge connection to lan.

For the lan (eth0) I can setup a bridge network and allow each virtual server to be visible in the lan and receive connections. But I'm not sure how to procede with the internet (eth1 and eth2) as each virtual server should receive external connections like web servers and the bridge is a problem because I have one dedicated ip only (sure the host should redirect from the real dedicated ip to the virtual machines using iptables or something).